# Missing required parameter To in the post body in react js axios using spring boot Twilio Api

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, twilio

I am having problem in executing spring boot post Twilio Api ..
The Api works fine while executing through spring boot.But when i integrated that API on my React js App using axios "Missing required parameter To in the post body" error occurs.
My spring boot Twilio sendOtpCode looks like this and this method on api works completly fine using Swagger in spring boot:

```
 @Override
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendOtpCode(TwilioSendDto twilioSendDto) {
        Twilio.init(accountSid,authToken);
        Verification verification=Verification.creator("VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",twilioSendDto.getPhoneNumber(),"sms").create();

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(verification.getStatus());


    }
```

My react code looks like this :

```
 sendOtpCode(phoneNumber,message){
    console.log("phone number", phoneNumber);
    return axios.post("http://localhost:8080/twilio",{
      method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
      data:phoneNumber,
 
    
    }
   
    );
```

```
AuthService.sendOtpCode(this.state.contactno).then(response =>{
            this.setState({
              message: response.data.message,
              successful: true
            });
```

I heard about the concept of querystring but that also did not helped me.

```
  sendOtpCode(phoneNumber,message){
    console.log("phone number", phoneNumber);
    return axios.post("http://localhost:8080/twilio",{
      method: 'POST',
  
      data:qs.stringify(phoneNumber),
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
      }
    
    }
   
    );
    

  }
```

TwilioSendDto class

```
package com.saptasoch.ecommerce.model.dto.twilioDto;

public class TwilioSendDto {
    private String phoneNumber;

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Twilio Controller:

```
ackage com.saptasoch.ecommerce.controller;

import com.saptasoch.ecommerce.model.dto.twilioDto.TwilioMessageDto;
import com.saptasoch.ecommerce.model.dto.twilioDto.TwilioSendDto;
import com.saptasoch.ecommerce.model.dto.twilioDto.TwilioVerifyDto;
import com.saptasoch.ecommerce.service.twilioService.TwilioService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/twilio")
@Api(value = "/twilio",tags = "twilio", description = "Twilio service")
public class TwilioController {

    @Autowired
    TwilioService twilioService;

    @PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<?> sendOtpCode(@RequestBody TwilioSendDto twilioSendDto){
        return twilioService.sendOtpCode(twilioSendDto);
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Can you compare the http requests being send from your react app and swagger by using your browser debugging Tools? The Spring boot application expects the payload normally as the POST body (depends on your configuration)

Comment: Can you attach TwilioSendDto class to the question.

Comment: @DaleKJames I have just attached my TwilioDto and TwilioController in the question .Please have a look .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request body you are passing to the API is not in the correct format.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/twilio", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber
        }});
```

`data` should be a JSON representing TwilioSendDto class.

Comment: i am sending data like this.. this.state={customerName:"",contactNo:"98xxxxxx"}. AuthService.sendOtpCode(this.state.contactNo); So what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem .

```
 sendOtpCode(phoneNumber) {
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:8080/twilio", {
        phoneNumber
        
      })
      
  }
```

It was my mistake i was adding headers unnecessarily .